# C++, read an array of number from a file

Tags: c++, io

The following is part of my C++ code, `argv[2]` is the path to the input file.
And I found out that though I get the correct number of element (`arr_size`) in the input file, the code in while loop didn't seem to be executed. The result is that all element in `arr[]` retain its original value(0).

```
ifstream inFile( argv[2] );

// get the number of element
int arr_size = distance(istream_iterator<int>(inFile), istream_iterator<int>() );

int * arr = new int[arr_size];

int idx(0);
while ( inFile >> arr[idx] ) {
    idx++;
}
```

I have tried

```
while ( !inFile.eof() ) {
    inFile >> arr[idx];
    idx++;
}
```

,but still get the same result.

The input file is just like below:

```
3 8 7 4 6 2 1 9 0 5
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: What is the value of `arr_size`?

Comment: Try searching the internet for "stackoverflow c++ read file array".  We really don't need more of these "similar but not exactly same" questions.

Comment: If you used `std::vector`, you would not have to worry about dynamic allocation nor buffer overrun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this line

```
int arr_size = distance(istream_iterator<int>(inFile), istream_iterator<int>() );
```

the file was already read to end.

You have to reset the `ifstream` using `seekg(0)` to start reading it again.

Also use the 1st version of your while loop, and better use a `std::vector<int>` and `push_back()` instead of managing the memory yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that when you do

```
int arr_size = distance(istream_iterator<int>(inFile), istream_iterator<int>() );
```

You actually read the file to determine how many times the `istream_iterator` can advance.  This meas that when you do to read from the file into the array you are already at the end of the file and nothing will be read.

To solve this you either need to seek back to the beginning of the file or instead of using `new` and `delete` use a `std::vector` like

```
std::vector data(istream_iterator<int>(inFile), istream_iterator<int>() );
```

And now you have a vector full of the file contents.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the call

```
int arr_size = distance(istream_iterator<int>(inFile), istream_iterator<int>() );
```

puts `inFile` at the end.

You need to reset it to  point to the start using [seekg](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg)

```
// Clear the state of the stream before calling seekg.
inFile.clear();
inFile.seekg(0);
```

should do it.

Comment: Before `seekg()` the stream state needs to be `clear()`ed: while the stream is in a failure state it will just ignore most requests.

Comment: @DietmarKühl, thanks for that. I agree.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend changing your code to use `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<int> database;
int datum = 0;
while (my_data_file >> datum)
{
  database.push_back(datum);
}
```

This eliminates the nasty issue of determining the quantity of numbers in a file, then allocate the amount of memory (correctly) and passing pointers, and finally deleting the memory.

Answer (score 0):

`std::istream_iterator<T>` is an *input iterator*: you can iterate over the sequence just once. Incrementing an input iterator consumes the corresponding element. You'd need a stronger iterator, e.g., *forward iterators* to traverse the sequence more than once.

If your input stream is an actual file you can either open it again or `clear()` the stream and then `seekg()` to the start of the stream to read it again. I'd personally read it to in a single pass storing the elements into a suitably resizable array, probably a`std::vector<T>`.

Note that your first loop is the preferred approach to read elements (when not using iterator). The use of `eof()` is just wrong! You certainly need to check the stream's state *after* an attempt to read the stream.